# Returning rows on a certain date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've looked through past questions - but couldn't find a good match. How do I return all MySQL rows where the column timestamp is on day X, where day X is contained in a PHP variable the following format: "13 Apr 2011", and the timestamp is in database is in the following format: "2011-02-25 22:00:17"?

```
SELECT * WHERE timestamp (need to add here)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%e %b %Y') = 'date coming from php'
```

(It's the opposite of andri's suggestion, it converts the timestamp into a string for comparision)

Comment: Do you know if this compares the times as strings or as time values?

Comment: This was ideal for me because it returns every result on that day, whereas using a unix timestamp would only return exact results or I'd have to make the query more complex.

Answer (score 3):

If the date string (in your PHP variable) has a consistent format, you can use the MySQL function [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert it into a DATETIME suitable for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT * WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = STR_TO_DATE('$var','%M %d %Y')
```

More [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)